# Smarty explode and foreach not working by only looping once

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty, explode

The `|explode:","` part of the code below doesn't appear to be working and the `foreach $widgets_ids` only ever loops once. I have tried adding `{$widgets_ids}` for debugging and this displays `Array`, so it is half working.

```
{foreach $layout_containers.rows as $row}           
<td class="layout_container" data-cid="{$row.container_id.fvalue}">
    Container: <strong>{$row.container_key.fvalue}</strong>
    <br />
    <a class="btnMed" rel="rename_container" href="javascript:;">Rename</a>
    <a class="btnMed" rel="delete_container" href="javascript:;">Delete</a>

    {if $row.widgets_ids.value}
        {assign var="widgets_ids" value=$row.widgets_ids.fvalue|explode:","}                        
        {foreach $widgets_ids as $widgets_id}
            {assign var="widget" value=$widgets.rows[$widgets_id]}
            <div data-widget="{$widget.id.fvalue}" class="widget ui-draggable">
                <img align="middle" src="{$HOME}{$TEMPLATE_HOME}/admin/images/icons/drag_drop.png" alt="{$widget.name.fvalue}" />
                {$widget.name.fvalue}
            </div>  
        {/foreach}
    {/if}

    {* droparea widget *}
    <div class="drop_area">drop area</div>
</td>
{/foreach}
```

Output array sent to the page:

```
    [widgets] => Array
        (
            [type] => Table
            [rowcount] => 5
            [name] => widgets
            [rows] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_id
                                    [value] => 1
                                    [fvalue] => 1
                                )
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_name
                                    [value] => Featured
                                    [fvalue] => Featured
                                )
                            [fixed] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_fixed
                                    [value] => 0
                                    [fvalue] => 0
                                )
                            [title] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_title
                                    [value] => We recommend these bookmakers
                                    [fvalue] => We recommend these bookmakers
                                )
                            [description] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_description
                                    [value] => 
                                    [fvalue] => 
                                )
                            [image] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_image
                                    [value] => 
                                    [fvalue] => 
                                )
                            [status] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_status
                                    [value] => ENABLED
                                    [fvalue] => Enabled
                                )
                            [template] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_template
                                    [value] => widgets/featured.tpl
                                    [fvalue] => widgets/featured.tpl
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_id
                                    [value] => 2
                                    [fvalue] => 2
                                )
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_name
                                    [value] => Tips
                                    [fvalue] => Tips
                                )
                            [fixed] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_fixed
                                    [value] => 0
                                    [fvalue] => 0
                                )
                            [title] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_title
                                    [value] => Betting Tips
                                    [fvalue] => Betting Tips
                                )
                            [description] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_description
                                    [value] => 
                                    [fvalue] => 
                                )
                            [image] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_image
                                    [value] => 
                                    [fvalue] => 
                                )
                            [status] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_status
                                    [value] => ENABLED
                                    [fvalue] => Enabled
                                )
                            [template] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_template
                                    [value] => widgets/tips.tpl
                                    [fvalue] => widgets/tips.tpl
                                )
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_id
                                    [value] => 3
                                    [fvalue] => 3
                                )
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_name
                                    [value] => Casion
                                    [fvalue] => Casion
                                )
                            [fixed] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_fixed
                                    [value] => 0
                                    [fvalue] => 0
                                )
                            [title] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_title
                                    [value] => Casion
                                    [fvalue] => Casion
                                )
                            [description] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_description
                                    [value] => <p>Best slot &amp; Live casino &pound;75 welcome bonus!</p>
                                    [fvalue] => <p>Best slot &amp; Live casino &pound;75 welcome bonus!</p>
                                )
                            [image] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_image
                                    [value] => /widgets/4f4ceb235bb9a_banner-casino.png
                                    [fvalue] => /widgets/4f4ceb235bb9a_banner-casino.png
                                )
                            [status] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_status
                                    [value] => ENABLED
                                    [fvalue] => Enabled
                                )
                            [template] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_template
                                    [value] => widgets/banner.tpl
                                    [fvalue] => widgets/banner.tpl
                                )
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_id
                                    [value] => 4
                                    [fvalue] => 4
                                )
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_name
                                    [value] => Football
                                    [fvalue] => Football
                                )
                            [fixed] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_fixed
                                    [value] => 0
                                    [fvalue] => 0
                                )
                            [title] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_title
                                    [value] => Football
                                    [fvalue] => Football
                                )
                            [description] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_description
                                    [value] => <p>Bet now &amp; wind a real football ball!</p>
                                    [fvalue] => <p>Bet now &amp; wind a real football ball!</p>
                                )
                            [image] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_image
                                    [value] => /widgets/4f4ceb44a7072_banner-football.png
                                    [fvalue] => /widgets/4f4ceb44a7072_banner-football.png
                                )
                            [status] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_status
                                    [value] => ENABLED
                                    [fvalue] => Enabled
                                )
                            [template] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_template
                                    [value] => widgets/banner.tpl
                                    [fvalue] => widgets/banner.tpl
                                )
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_id
                                    [value] => 5
                                    [fvalue] => 5
                                )
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_name
                                    [value] => Horses
                                    [fvalue] => Horses
                                )
                            [fixed] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_fixed
                                    [value] => 0
                                    [fvalue] => 0
                                )
                            [title] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_title
                                    [value] => Horses
                                    [fvalue] => Horses
                                )
                            [description] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_description
                                    [value] => <p>Bet now &amp; win borse statue!</p>
                                    [fvalue] => <p>Bet now &amp; win borse statue!</p>
                                )
                            [image] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_image
                                    [value] => /widgets/4f4ceb66381ab_banner-horses.png
                                    [fvalue] => /widgets/4f4ceb66381ab_banner-horses.png
                                )
                            [status] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_status
                                    [value] => ENABLED
                                    [fvalue] => Enabled
                                )
                            [template] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => widgets.widget_template
                                    [value] => widgets/banner.tpl
                                    [fvalue] => widgets/banner.tpl
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
```

Layout_containers

```
[layout_containers] => Array
    (
        [type] => Table
        [rowcount] => 3
        [name] => layout_containers
        [header] => Array
            (
                [names] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => container_id
                        [1] => id
                        [2] => container_key
                        [3] => container_title
                        [4] => widgets_ids
                    )
                [container_id] => Array
                    (
                        [enabled] => 0
                        [sort] => ASC
                        [nextsort] => DESC
                        [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_id
                        [label] => Container Id
                        [url] => /gambler_compendium/admin/layout/widgets/id/1/layout_containers.layout_containers.layout_container_id/desc
                        [formname] => layout_containers.layout_containers.layout_container_id
                        [hidden] =>
                    )
                [id] => Array
                    (
                        [enabled] => 0
                        [sort] => ASC
                        [nextsort] => DESC
                        [name] => layout_containers.layout_id
                        [label] => Id
                        [url] => /gambler_compendium/admin/layout/widgets/id/1/layout_containers.layout_containers.layout_id/desc
                        [formname] => layout_containers.layout_containers.layout_id
                        [hidden] => 
                    )
                [container_key] => Array
                    (
                        [enabled] => 1
                        [sort] => ASC
                        [nextsort] => DESC
                        [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_key
                        [label] => Container Key
                        [url] => /gambler_compendium/admin/layout/widgets/id/1/layout_containers.layout_containers.layout_container_key/desc
                        [formname] => layout_containers.layout_containers.layout_container_key
                        [hidden] => 
                    )
                [container_title] => Array
                    (
                        [enabled] => 0
                        [sort] => ASC
                        [nextsort] => DESC
                        [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_title
                        [label] => Container Title
                        [url] => /gambler_compendium/admin/layout/widgets/id/1/layout_containers.layout_containers.layout_container_title/desc
                        [formname] => layout_containers.layout_containers.layout_container_title
                        [hidden] => 
                    )
                [widgets_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [enabled] => 0
                        [sort] => ASC
                        [nextsort] => DESC
                        [name] => layout_containers.widgets_ids
                        [label] => Widgets Ids
                        [url] => /gambler_compendium/admin/layout/widgets/id/1/layout_containers.layout_containers.widgets_ids/desc
                        [formname] => layout_containers.layout_containers.widgets_ids
                        [hidden] => 
                    )
            )
        [field] => Array
            (
                [names] => Array
                    (
                    )
            )
        [rows] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [container_id] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_id
                                [value] => 113
                                [fvalue] => 113
                            )
                        [id] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_id
                                [value] => 1
                                [fvalue] => 1
                            )
                        [container_key] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_key
                                [value] => sidebarLeft
                                [fvalue] => sidebarLeft
                            )
                        [container_title] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_title
                                [value] => 
                                [fvalue] => 
                            )
                        [widgets_ids] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.widgets_ids
                                [value] => 1,2
                                [fvalue] => 1,2
                            )
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [container_id] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_id
                                [value] => 115
                                [fvalue] => 115
                            )
                        [id] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_id
                                [value] => 1
                                [fvalue] => 1
                            )
                        [container_key] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_key
                                [value] => sidebarRight_banners
                                [fvalue] => sidebarRight_banners
                            )
                        [container_title] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_title
                                [value] => 
                                [fvalue] => 
                            )
                        [widgets_ids] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.widgets_ids
                                [value] => 3,4,5
                                [fvalue] => 3,4,5
                            )
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [container_id] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_id
                                [value] => 114
                                [fvalue] => 114
                            )
                        [id] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_id
                                [value] => 1
                                [fvalue] => 1
                            )
                        [container_key] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_key
                                [value] => sidebarRight_bannersList
                                [fvalue] => sidebarRight_bannersList
                            )
                        [container_title] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.layout_container_title
                                [value] => 
                                [fvalue] => 
                            )
                        [widgets_ids] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => layout_containers.widgets_ids
                                [value] => 
                                [fvalue] => 
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{$widgets_ids = ","|explode:"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"}
{foreach $widgets_ids as $widget_id}
    {$widget_id}
{/foreach}
```

works perfectly fine. You have some problems in your code.

---

```
{assign var="widgets_ids" value=$row.widgets_ids.fvalue|explode:","}
```

should be

```
{assign var="widgets_ids" value=","|explode:$row.widgets_ids.fvalue}
```

or

```
{$widgets_ids = ","|explode:$row.widgets_ids.fvalue}
```

---

```
{foreach $widgets_ids as $widgets_id}
```

should probably be

```
{foreach $widgets_ids as $widget_id}
```

---

```
{assign var="widget" value=$widgets.rows[$widget_id]}
```

may also be

```
{assign var="widget" value=$widgets.rows.$widget_id}
```

Comment: It was the explode I had mixed up that was causing the problem.